# Background Image in python34 Is not appearning on run time

Tags: python, image, tkinter

Can anyone please help me here. I am using python34 and the below mentioned code cnippet does not yield any interpretaion error. But it does not show the picture when run.

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk



class MyApp(Frame):
 def __init__(self,parent):
    Frame.__init__(self,parent)
    self.parent=parent
    self.createUI()

 def createUI(self):
    self.grid()
    raw_data=Image.open("abc.gif")
    image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(raw_data)
    label=tk.Label(image = image)
    label.grid(column=0,row=0)


root=tk.Tk()
app=MyApp(root)
app.mainloop()
```

although the following code works fine.
    import tkinter as tk
    from PIL import ImageTk
    import urllib.request

```
root = tk.Tk()

raw_data=Image.open("abc.gif")
image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(raw_data)
label = tk.Label(image=image)
label.pack()
tk.mainloop()
```

PLease sugest what I am missing or doing wrong.

Comment: Your imports and code don't seem to match up

Answer (score -2):

when you move to a class based structure, you need to keep a reference to the image to prevent python for garbage collecting it, usually this is done by adding it to a list that belongs to the class:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk
class MyApp(Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        self.parent=parent
        self.createUI()
        self.images = []


    def createUI(self):
        self.grid()
        raw_data=Image.open("abc.gif")
        image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(raw_data)
        self.images.append(image)
        label=tk.Label(image = image)
        label.grid(column=0,row=0)


root=tk.Tk()
app=MyApp(root)
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: maybe it's because this isn't related to a "class based system"? The problem isn't related to classes at all -- you can have the same issues without classes. The problem is simply that local variables get garbage-collected, which destroys the image.

Comment: i can see your point, and perhaps i could have made it clearer, but i did specifically say it was because he needed to keep a reference to the object to prevent it being garbage collected...